# Landscape only in xaml page

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, landscape

how i can set my page.xaml only in landscape mode? . i'm developing a cross Platform app in xamarin forms using xaml/#. thanks you

Comment: It depends if you want all pages in landscape only, or just one single page (please extend your question with more details). You can find base informations about device orientation here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/device-orientation/

Comment: only one page, infact i said "page.xaml" :)